# Ubuntu says directory exists and directory not found at the same time

Tags: command-line, directory

```
manas@manas-Aspire-E5-575G:~$ sudo git clone https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin.git && cp katoolin/katoolin.py /usr/bin/katoolin
[sudo] password for manas: 
fatal: destination path 'katoolin' already exists and is not an empty directory.
manas@manas-Aspire-E5-575G:~$ cd /usr/bin/
manas@manas-Aspire-E5-575G:/usr/bin$ rm -R katoolin
rm: cannot remove 'katoolin': No such file or directory
manas@manas-Aspire-E5-575G:/usr/bin$
```

You see here first it says /usr/bin/katoolin already exists but when I am trying to delete it it says no such directory.
Output of "ls -la /usr/bin/katoolin"

```
manas@manas-Aspire-E5-575G:~$ ls -la /usr/bin/katoolin
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/katoolin': No such file or directory
manas@manas-Aspire-E5-575G:~$
```

Comment: Why you are trying to clone git-repository to home folder with `sudo`, but try to copy file without `sudo`? What do you want to achieve? Please add output of `ls -la /usr/bin/katoolin` to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short answer

It's not the last command, but the first part that causes the complaint. You must have cloned the repo before, and it exists in your home directory. :)

Comment: @ManasSingh That would be totally up to you.  You could just leave this here in case someone else might experience a similar problem as you.  I recommend keeping it here.

Comment: @ManasSingh why would you? it is a clear question, and I bet you are not the first, nor the last.